# How to load scripts without the get_header() function

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, buddypress

I'm looking for a way to scripts that a plugin need to run without the `get_header();` function

**here's a backstory about what's happening**

I'm working on BuddyPress plugin, specifically the template part of it.
I created new template, define the file and everything is running without errors.

The template I'm working on doesn't use the `get_header();` function because I don't want the header in that template to be visible.

A picture of how's the code looks like:

```
/* 
* This Is A BuddyPress Template [ With No Header ]
*/

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

<div id="primary" <?php generate_do_element_classes( 'content' ); ?>>
        <main id="main" <?php generate_do_element_classes( 'main' ); ?>>
            <?php
            /**
             * generate_before_main_content hook.
             *
             * @since 0.1
             */
            do_action( 'generate_before_main_content' );

            if ( generate_has_default_loop() ) {
                while ( have_posts() ) :

                    the_post();

                    generate_do_template_part( 'page' );

                endwhile;
            }

    


    get_footer();
```

Everything is good to this point: BuddyPress loads and the profile user loads.

The issue is that the members page stucks at `Loading members of the community. Please wait.` and every non static page is stuck.

Well this is happing because some scripts are not loading in `<head> </head>`
but when I call the `get_header();` function

all the scripts load

I tried to search about it in Stackoverflow but haven't found anything I needed and some scripts are not working and it's undefined

like the  `wp_print_head_scripts();` - it not printing any scripts and this method didn't work

I also tired to load it directly from the same template like

and that didn't work ether
So I'm stuck here. Anybody? if I forgot something please tell me I'll appreciate that (:

Comment: I retried to link the .js file and this time i checked the dev tools in chrome console - and i find out that .js file turns from yellow to purple and the code color change why's that ?? 


here's a pic with the file imported with `get_header()`:

Answer (score -1):

sorry , i totally forgot about the  `wp_head():`

`wp_head()` loads all the scripts needed without the header